# How to print all results of a JSON API call

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization

I'm making a web-app that needs data through an API. I am trying to re-purpose some of the developer's example code of a different function than the original code was written for. Here's the important part:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlPrefix + "getthingjson/" + Key);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            // Parse returned JSON into data
            //
            using (var web = new WebClient())
            {
                web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                var jsonString = responseFromServer;
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var ThingsList = jss.Deserialize<List<Things>>(jsonString);
                string ThingsListStr = "";

                foreach (Things x in ThingsList)
                    ThingsListStr = ThingsListStr + ", " + x.Name;

                MessageBox.Show(ThingsListStr);
            }
```

I know that I need to change 'Name' in order to get a different piece of info on the 'Things' call. The thing is, I need to call results on a different function, instead of 'Things' say 'Details'. I don't know what to look for in place of 'Name' since when I search that it returns nothing. How could I just deserialize all of what JSON returns? Sorry if my terminology was off or I made a simple mistake, I'm new to JSON and C#. Thanks!

Comment: So you need to get Details instead of Name from Things entity?

Comment: No I need to call 'Details' instead of 'Thing' and not call just one result like just 'Name' but instead print everything it brings back. I know that it brings back more than one thing, I just dont know the specific result to call as it wasn't listed in the API instruction google doc.

Comment: Ok, please place breakpoint after string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); line and expore value of responseFromServer variable, add JSON example to question description, then I will edit my answer according to result that you receive.

Comment: I figured it out I think. I didn't know you could right click a variable while you run it to get its value. I think I can take it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Details instead of Name property you should:

1. Check if you receive this data in json.
2. Adjust your c# class with Details property if it doesn't exist. (Go to Things class and add new Details property)
3. Change

   ```
   ThingsListStr = ThingsListStr + ", " + x.Name;
   ```

   to

   ```
   ThingsListStr = ThingsListStr + ", " + x.Details;
   ```